# How to run app in backgorund amdroid studio/java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want my app to write to my bluetooth receiver commend until i hold a button, then the commend will change and continue when i release. (it will send 0 always until i will hold, and then it will send 1 and when i release 0 again).
I tried to make a thread it will send the 0 that is working but when i hold the button it sends 1(as intened) but when i release it doesnt sends 0 again.

```
package com.example.bluetooth;
import static android.text.TextUtils.concat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<String> deviceName = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> devicesDict = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Object[] devices;
    EditText InputTI;
    Button sendB;
    Button commend1B;
    String message;
    Boolean connected = false;
    Boolean sending = false;
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (blueAdapter != null) {
            if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                if(bondedDevices.size() > 0) {

                    devices = (Object []) bondedDevices.toArray();
                    Log.i("devices:","devices[0]"+devices[0]);
                    Log.i("devices:","devices[1]"+devices[1]);
                    Log.i("devices:","devices[2]"+devices[2]);
                    BluetoothDevice result = null;
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : bondedDevices) {
                        devicesDict.put(""+device.getName(), ""+device);
                    }
                    Log.i("dict","dict"+devicesDict);

                    deviceName.add("Select:");
                    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : devicesDict.entrySet()){
                        deviceName.add(entry.getKey()+";"+entry.getValue());
                    }

                    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ListSp);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deviceName);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
            } else {
                Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
            }
        }

        InputTI = findViewById(R.id.InputTI);
        sendB = findViewById(R.id.sendB);
        commend1B = findViewById(R.id.commend1B);
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        commend1B.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                sending = true;
                try {
                    Log.i("sending","sending 1");
                    write("1#");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sending = false;
                return false;
            }

        });




        sendB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("sendState","state"+sending);
                message = InputTI.getText().toString()+"#";
                try {
                    write(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String[] splitted;
                splitted = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString().split(";");
                if (blueAdapter != null) {
                    if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        if (!adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select:")) {
                            for (Object o : devices) {
                                if (o.toString().equals(splitted[1])) {
                                    connected = true;
                                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) o;
                                    ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();

                                    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
                                    try {
                                        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {

                                        socket.connect();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        Log.e("ConnectFail", "Socket.connect() Failed", e);
                                        //e.printStackTrace();

                                        break;
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    if (connected && !sending) {
                                        Log.i("sending", "sending 021");
                                        thread.start();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            connected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        }
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while (connected && !sending) {
                    try {

                        Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
                        write("0#");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    };




    public void write(String s) throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
    }
```

Comment: On the command1B you set an onTouchListener, not an onClickListener.  An touch event is sent every time you touch the view, release the view, or move so much as a pixel.  You could be sending 100s of 1s with this code.  Instead, you want to filter the motion events and listen only to the ones you want to react to.  And using the motion of the touch to send a continuous stream of 1s is a bad idea-  there will be no cadence to it, the timing would be totally random.  Especially since motion events can be combined.  If you want to send a stream of 1s, use a timer or thread.

Comment: I want it to send 1s while I'm touching the button. The 1s are sent to Bluetooth and to my Arduino so I want it to send a lot. But I'm having a problem detecting when I release the button

Comment: Releasing the button would be an  ACTION_UP event in the motion event.  But that is NOT a good way of sending continuous ones.  You really ought to do a timer sending a 1 at a fixed interval.  This way you could send a 1 every 10ms, or 100ms, or 20s and you won't know.

Comment: At the end I didn't use the service found another better way thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

To run background services you need to use Service class or/and Background Threads.

Service documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

BackGround Threads: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading